# the record is deleted from the database, but the table with new data is not displayed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

code apex

```
@AuraEnabled 
   public static void deleteContact(String contactId) {  
       Contact tobeDeleted = null;
    for (Contact a : [SELECT Id FROM Contact])
        if (a.Id == contactId) {
            tobeDeleted = a;
            break;
        }
    if (tobeDeleted != null) { 
        Delete tobeDeleted; 
    }   
   }
```

code js

```
import { LightningElement, track, api} from 'lwc';
import getContactsList from '@salesforce/apex/ManageRecordsController.getContactsList';  
 import getContactsCount from '@salesforce/apex/ManageRecordsController.getContactsCount'; 
 import deleteContact from '@salesforce/apex/ManageRecordsController.deleteContact';


export default class RecordList extends LightningElement {
   @track contacts;  
   @track error;  
   @api currentpage;  
   @api pagesize;  
   @track searchKey;  
   totalpages;  
   localCurrentPage = null;  
   isSearchChangeExecuted = false; 

   @api sortingColumn = 'Name';
   @api sortingOrder = ' ASC ';
   @api contactId = ' ';   

   handleChange(event){
       if(this.sortingOrder === ' ASC '){
        this.sortingOrder = ' DESC ';
       } else {
         this.sortingOrder = ' ASC ';
       }   
        this.sortingColumn = event.target.title;

       this.isSearchChangeExecuted = false;   
       this.currentpage = 1;       
   }

   deleteRecord(event){    
    this.contactId = event.target.dataset.recordid;   

     // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
     if (window.confirm('Are you sure to DELETE?')) deleteContact({contactId: this.contactId});  
     this.contacts = null;
     this.isSearchChangeExecuted = false;         
    }


   handleKeyChange(event) {  
     if (this.searchKey !== event.target.value) {  
       this.isSearchChangeExecuted = false;  
       this.searchKey = event.target.value;  
       this.currentpage = 1;  
     }  
   }  
   renderedCallback() {    
     if (this.isSearchChangeExecuted && (this.localCurrentPage === this.currentpage)) { 
       return;  
     }  
     this.isSearchChangeExecuted = true;  
     this.localCurrentPage = this.currentpage;  
     getContactsCount({ searchString: this.searchKey })  
       .then(recordsCount => {  
         this.totalrecords = recordsCount;  
         if (recordsCount !== 0 && !isNaN(recordsCount)) {  
           this.totalpages = Math.ceil(recordsCount / this.pagesize);  
           getContactsList({ pagenumber: this.currentpage, numberOfRecords: recordsCount, pageSize: this.pagesize, searchString: this.searchKey, sortingColumn: this.sortingColumn, sortingOrder: this.sortingOrder })  
             .then(contactList => {  
               this.contacts = contactList; 
               this.error = undefined;  
             })  
             .catch(error => {  
               this.error = error;  
               this.contacts = undefined;  
             });  
         } else {  
           this.contacts = [];  
           this.totalpages = 1;  
           this.totalrecords = 0;  
         }  
         const event = new CustomEvent('recordsload', {  
           detail: recordsCount  
         });  
         this.dispatchEvent(event);  
       })  
       .catch(error => {  
         this.error = error;  
         this.totalrecords = undefined;  
       });  
    }  
}
```

if you refresh the page, updated data appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWC is basically based on `promises`. All the server calls will return a promise.

Firstly, your apex method is iterating over all database contacts untill it finds the required contact. It has to be optimised. Also you need to return

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static String deleteContact(String contactId) {  
    try{
        delete [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id=:contactId];
        return 'SUCCESS';
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then you need to handle the promise `deleteContact`:

```
if (window.confirm('Are you sure to DELETE?'))
        deleteContact({ contactId: this.contactId })
            .then((response) => {
                this.contacts = this.contacts.filter((con) => con.Id !== this.contactId);
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.contacts = undefined;
            });
```

Here you have 2 options to do in promise:

1. As shown above just filter out the deleted contact in JS itself OR
2. Get the new contacts list from apex. This can be done returning `List<Contact>` in deleteContact apex method.